# Vector Isn't Creating Multiple Class Objects

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

I have a `vector` that stores multiple `class` `object`s for later access. This way my program can create new `object`s during runtime. This is done like so:

```
vector<Person> peopleVector;
peopleVector.push_back(Person(name, age));
for (int i = 0; i < peopleVector.size(); i++) {
    cout << peopleVector[i].name << endl;
}
```

This function should print out each `object`s "name" every time the code runs (it's a function that runs multiple times). However, when I run this, somehow the `vector` does not increase in size. If you add `cout << peopleVector.size();` to that code, you will find that each time it runs, it gets one (obviously assuming you also have the `class` code which I have below).

I'm curious why I can't create multiple `object`s in the class.

## Class.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Person {
public:
    Person(string personName, int personAge);
    string name;
    int age;
};



Person::Person(string personName, int personAge) {
    name = personName;
    age = personAge;
}
```

## Main.cpp

```
#include "Class.h"
#include <random>

int main() {
    // Necessary for random numbers
    srand(time(0));

    string name = names[rand() % 82]; // Array with a lot of names
    int age = 4 + (rand() % 95);
}

// Create a new person
void newPerson(string name, int age) {
    vector<Person> peopleVector;
    peopleVector.push_back(Person(name, age));
    for (int i = 0; i < peopleVector.size(); i++) {
        cout << peopleVector[i].name << endl;
    }
}
```

Just FYI those `#include`s might be a little bit off because I took that code out of a large section that had like 15 includes.

Comment: You never call `newPerson` in your example so what did you expect to happen? Plus you keep making a new `std::vector<Person>` each time you call `newPerson` so that `vector` will never be greater than size `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an empty vector each time you call your `newPerson()` function, and then you add a single person to it.

You then display the contents of that vector. What else can it contain, other than the single person that you added?

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Every time a function runs, all local variables inside the function are re-created in their default state. That means that every time you call `newPerson`, it just recreates `peopleVector`.

### Solution

There are two solutions:

- Have `newPerson` take a reference to a vector, and add it on to that
- make `peopleVector` static, so that it isn't re-initialized every time

#### First solution:

```
// Create a new person; add it to peopleVector
// The function takes a reference to the vector you want to add it to
void newPerson(string name, int age, vector<Person>& peopleVector) {
    peopleVector.push_back(Person(name, age));
    for (int i = 0; i < peopleVector.size(); i++) {
        cout << peopleVector[i].name << endl;
    }
}
```

#### Second solution: mark `peopleVector` as `static`

```
// create a new person; add it to peopleVector
void newPerson(string name, int age) {
    // Marking peopleVector as static prevents it from being re-initialized
    static vector<Person> peopleVector; 
    peopleVector.push_back(Person(name, age));
    for (int i = 0; i < peopleVector.size(); i++) {
        cout << peopleVector[i].name << endl;
    }
}
```